# How to efficently update WPF MainWindow from an async task

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, dispatcher

Is this an acceptable approach to update WPF MainWindow from an `async task`, using events thrown from a `public static class`?

In MainWindow.cs, I subscribe to  `UI.TaskCompleted` event
  In UI.cs, I subscribe to `AsyncTaskActions.TaskCompleted`  event.

Using this pattern, `AsyncTaskActions.TaskCompleted` is raised with a async task is completed.  UI catch the event and raise `UI.TaskCompleted`.  This way, the event is catch in MainWindow code where I can use `Displacher.Invoke` to refresh the displayed page.  The end result is I get a page refresh when a task is completed and the task still runs `asynchronously`.

> **Application design summary:**
>
> MainWindow: main window which can have several different page classes
>   in content area within the main window.
>
> Common.cs  public static class contains a number of common methods
>   through the UI in the application.
>
> AsyncTaskActions.cs - class with a number of `async` common methods
>   (ie download file)

Code snippets:

```
    public partial class MainWindow 
        public MainWindow()
        {    
           UI.TaskCompleted += UI_TaskCompleted; 
        }

        void UI_TaskCompleted(EventArgs e)
        {
           Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(this.PageRefresh));
        }

       public void PageRefresh()        
       {
           var page = ((ContentArea)).Content;
           if (page == null) return;

            switch (page.GetType().Name)
            {
                case "SearchPage":
                    ((SearchPage) page).SearchParts();
                    break;
                case "LegoPartPage":
                    ((LegoPartPage) page).LoadData();
                    break;
                case "LegoSetPage":
                    ((LegoSetPage) page).LoadData();
                    break;
                case "MainPage":
                    ((MainPage) page).LoadData();
                    break;
                case "MiniFigPage":
                    ((MiniFigPage) page).LoadData();
                    break;
            }
        }
   }

    public static class UI
    {
       public delegate void TaskComplete(EventArgs e);
       public static event TaskComplete TaskCompleted;

        public static async Task<int> DownloadPriceSummaryAsync(String itemNo, Int64 colorId)
        {
            var wAsyncTaskClasses = new AsyncTaskClasses();
            wAsyncTaskClasses.TaskCompleted += wAsyncTaskClasses_TaskCompleted;
            Task<HtmlDocument> task = wAsyncTaskClasses.DownloadPriceGuide(string.Format(Common.BrickLinkPrice, itemNo, colorId), itemNo, colorId);
            return await  wAsyncTaskClasses.ParsePriceSummaryAsync(task, itemNo, colorId);
        }
 }


public class AsyncTaskActions
{
    public delegate void TaskComplete(object sender, EventArgs e);
    public event TaskComplete TaskCompleted;

    public async Task<int> ParsePriceSummaryAsync(Task<HtmlDocument> task, string itemNo, Int64 colorId)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => ParsePriceSummary(task, itemNo, colorId));
    }

    public int ParsePriceSummary(Task<HtmlDocument> task, string itemNo, Int64 colorId)
    {
         ... some code....

        if (null != TaskCompleted)
        {
            TaskCompleted(this, new EventArgs());
        }

        return recordCount;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are marshaling all events to the UI context with `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` and that appears safe.

As usual, **if it works, it works!**

---

As an aside - there is not much about this design that I would personally consider acceptable. Is it reasonable to assume you are from an procedural or functional background? It might help to throw this at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for more information and some OO tips.

Comment: Actually, I did that first.  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108771/c-how-to-efficently-update-wpf-mainwindow-from-an-async-task